# How to get started converting PHP app to Native App

Tags: php, cordova

I'm have developed a couple of apps in iPhone and Android, and am now looking to understand how Phone Gap fits into the mobile picture. Since I have an existing database-driven (mySql) web application coded in php, css and javascript, I'd like to convert to an iPhone and/or Android app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

What I'd like to do for now is find some tutorial to code a simple PhoneGap based app. Then graduate to another slightly more complex one which uses html5 for local data storage. I've started working through Jonathan Stark's excellent tutorial, "Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript" at http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/index.html. But jQtouch figures significantly in that tutorial, and I would prefer to use the more up-to-date jQuery Mobile library if at all possible.

Also, from what little I've been able to glimmer thusfar, it may be necessary to restructure the web app so the Javascript is separate from the PHP. This seems like a lot of work for something which I was hoping to just put a Phone Gap wrapper around.

So my two questions are 1) can someone please advise on good tutorial with examples to get untracked on PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile development?

And 2, confirm that ripping the PHP out of the app is my only option in order to get it to run as a web app?

Comment: If you have the experience in building native app, i would just stick with that.  I'm working on a phonegap app right now and it's just too slow.  The performance is not quite there yet I think.  I would stay away from jquery mobile and use plain javascript as much as you can or xui.

Comment: I like the idea of multiple device coverage. Maintaining multiple code bases is already a hassle. Then again I'm starting to get pretty comfortable with iPhone. It's confusing. Is your app a game which demands speed, or heavy db, or just something simple?

Comment: I definetely agree about multiple device coverage.  That's why we went with phonegap route.  In the end, I think that was a mistake. The app is a mini crm app that use a local sqlite.  The amount of data is not that big. 15 tables with at most 100 rows on the largest table. The data is updated by calling a webservice each time the user login.

Comment: Would it have been workable to go with maintaining all the user data on the web, with no local repository?

Comment: that was slower since it will force it to fetch everything each time.

Comment: as @atbebtg says jquery mobile has a poor performance compared with XUI, BUT it will avoid you big headaches helping with the screens layout and the magically fit of the UI elements...that´s are basically the two side of the balance.

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta  is correct.  jquery mobile will save you a lot and i mean A LOT of work in term of UI and all navigation and page transition.  However it comes at a STEEP price.

Comment: @atbebtg - is it possible that adding some indexes to the DB could improve performance? Does the initial load of the table take longest, or is it within the app? Where's the bottleneck? I didn't know that PhoneGap was so slow, or is it jQuery Mobile rather that's hanging things up?

Comment: i think indexes will certain help.  its slow almost eveywhere really.  there is a lag on almost anything.  I would definetely suggest you give it a try and create 2 pages where you go back and fort.  Don't take my word for it.  I'm not an expert on it and my code could definetely use some optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best starting point would be to look at:

Introduction to PhoneGap: http://phonegap.com/start

Introduction to Jquery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/

Looking at how they work together: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

On #2: You'd have to get rid of the PHP portions, or at least, if you do need to load dynamic content, seperate it out and factor them into code that integrates with your chosen mobile framework. The jQuery Mobile site offers some downloadable examples which demonstrate how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can not deploy a PHP application including the web server into a native (PhoneGap) app. But you can use a native PhoneGap app to access a webpage which is located in the internet.

I once used the rendered HTML output of a PHP application for a native PhoneGap app. (I copied the HTML files manually into the www folder of PhoneGap.)

Comment: This might be the quickest solution, though probably not the most elegant. How did you collect and rend the html output? Parse it out of server response somehow using javascript? I guess it would be also possible for me to add some restful api to the PHP app and have the javascript parse through that, correct?

Comment: My job was to convert XML files into HTML, lot of pages. Then created an index page and also added some header and footer stuff to all files... copied all into the PhoneGap www dir. Thats it.

Comment: So, was this a one-off creation of a static set of pages? Or were the pages recreated dynamically based on the user interaction? Thx.

Comment: no simply static. all interaction was javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Basically what you need to do is to create some sort of SaaS structure, where your PHP/MySQL serves the content and the mobile application just consumes everything via JavaScript.

So, you do the normal server side code that delivers everything in JSON, and then, you create a basic HTML application for the PhoneGat framework that consumes everything via jquery $.getJSON

Take a look at this example:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.getJSON/index.html